# Piece of state changes in parent component but not in child components React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component tree that looks as so:

```
<Profile>
   <FollowersAndFollowing>
      <Overlay>
         {children}
      </Overlay>
   </FollowersAndFollowing>
</Profile>
```

In `<Profile/>` I have a piece of state holding a boolean value:

`const [showFollowers, setShowFollowers] = useState(false)`

I am trying to prop funnel this piece of state to all of my components. In my `<Profile/>` I have these two functions.

```
  const handleShowFollowers = () => setShowFollowers(true)
  const handleHideFollowers = () => setShowFollowers(false)

  console.log('from profile', showFollowers) // logs true, then logs false
```

**IN PROFILE**

```
{showFollowers ? <FollowersAndFollowing showFollowers={showFollowers} handleHideFollowers={handleHideFollowers} /> : null}
```

**FOLLOWERS AND FOLLOWING**

```
const FollowersAndFollowing = ({ showFollowers, handleHideFollowers }) => {

  console.log('from followers', showFollowers) // logs true, then logs nothing at all

  return (
    <Overlay isShowing={showFollowers} currentTopPosition={0}>
      <h1>followers and following</h1>
      <button onClick={handleHideFollowers}>BACK</button>
    </Overlay>
  )
}
```

**OVERLAY**

```
const Overlay = ({ isShowing, children, currentTopPosition }) => {

  console.log('from overlay', isShowing) // logs true, then logs nothing at all

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isShowing) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
    }
  }, [isShowing])

  return (
    <div className={isShowing ? overlayStyles.showOverlay : overlayStyles.overlay} style={{ top: `${currentTopPosition}px` }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I trigger `handleShowFollowers` from my `<Profile/>` component I see `showFollowers` as true for all three components.

However when I trigger `handleHideFollowers` from the `<FollowersAndFollowing/>` component I see `showFollowers` flip to false in the parent component (profile) but not in any of the other two components. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
{showFollowers ? <FollowersAndFollowing showFollowers={showFollowers} handleHideFollowers={handleHideFollowers} /> : null}
```

If `showFollowers` is false then your `FollowersAndFollowing` component won't render at all, that's why the `console.log`s do no log.

If you change it to just this:

```
<FollowersAndFollowing showFollowers={showFollowers} handleHideFollowers={handleHideFollowers} />
```

You can then handle hiding elements deeper down inside the children components and it should work fine.

Comment: That has fixed it nicely! Thanks!

Comment: It's all a pleasure :)